# How to get access to directory/subdirectories/subdirectories?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that can observe files in directory and subdirectories, but it can't get access to files in the level 3 of subdirectories .
I just need to observe some file changes and modify them so I need to touch all file in the directory recursively

Example: get access to `home` and `home/directories`, but can't touch `home/sub` (sub)directories. How to make that possible?

I want to see all files in the folder 
The code I have is:

```
 co(function* () {
  let close = yield awatch("./*", (event, filename) => {

    //Observing any single changement in file of ext ".html" in local directory 


    if (cropping_extension(filename) == ".html") {
      /**
       * Reading the contain of a file and keep it inside a string 
       */
      console.log(cropping_path(filename));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have access to all the files in the folder you just need to change ./* to => ./**/*
So in your code you just need to change this part :

let close = yield awatch(" ./**/* ", (event, filename)

Answer (score 0):

How are you hosting the directories? For example, if you're using Express (NodeJS) you'd want to elect a static directory to host all of your assets.

Comment: It is just a script I don't use express I just want to observe changes  of  type of file (.html) in my local folder

Comment: Sorry, I'll need more info.. can't really help with what's been given already..

Comment: I am trying to make a script able to see in every files in a folder recursively in javascript .The script must be able to see any see change for every files in the folder folder in the this folder recursively

Comment: Finaly I find a way to do it it was just  =>  ../**/*